# Gremlin find lightest path between vertices

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, gremlinpython

I am pretty new to Gremlin and I am trying to find within my graph the **lightest paths** from *source_id* vertex to *target_id* vertex. (On some edges I have weights and on others I don't)

To get the shortest path I can with:

```
             g.V()
            .has("id", source_id)
            .repeat(outV().simplePath())
            .until(has("id", target_id))
            .path()
            .limit(3)
            .toList()
        )
```

I have read [this reference book](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.1-SNAPSHOT/recipes/)

and it suggested to use something like:

```
             g.V()
            .has("id", source_id)
            .repeat(out()).simplePath())
            .until(has("id", target_id))
            .path()
            .by(coalesce(values("weight"), constant(0.0)))
            .limit(limit)
            .toList()
        )
```

This is not working and returning the weights of the paths,
how can I achieve this with Gremlin? should first get the paths, calculate their weights and then sort them by the weights? there must be an easier and intuitive way for this basic need. (if it were neo4j I could just run Dijkstra's algorithm)

Would appreciate some help here,
thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the paths with the lowest overall score? If so storing those weights in a `sack` and then ordering by the `sack` value is one way to do this. If you can confirm that is what you need I can provide an example. The snippet you found handles the case where edges may not have weights but does not try to order things.

Comment: I went ahead and added an answer using a small example graph.

Answer (score 1):

I created the following example graph to help illustrate this answer.

```
gremlin> g.addV('A').as('a').
......1>   addV('B').as('b').
......2>   addV('C').as('c').
......3>   addV('D').as('d').
......4>   addV('E').as('e').
......5>   addV('F').as('f').
......6>   addV('G').as('g').
......7>   addV('H').as('h').
......8>   addV('Z').as('z').
......9>   addE('knows').from('a').to('b').property('weight',0.2).
.....10>   addE('knows').from('a').to('c').property('weight',0.5).
.....11>   addE('knows').from('a').to('f').property('weight',3.5).
.....12>   addE('knows').from('b').to('c').property('weight',0.1).
.....13>   addE('knows').from('c').to('d').property('weight',0.3).
.....14>   addE('knows').from('c').to('e').property('weight',0.2).
.....15>   addE('knows').from('c').to('f').
.....16>   addE('knows').from('d').to('f').property('weight',0.1).
.....17>   addE('knows').from('d').to('g').property('weight',2.0).
.....18>   addE('knows').from('f').to('g').property('weight',0.9).
.....19>   addE('knows').from('f').to('h').property('weight',0.3).
.....20>   addE('knows').from('f').to('z').property('weight',0.1).
.....21>   addE('knows').from('h').to('z').property('weight',0.2).iterate()
```

The following routes exist from A to Z (regardless of edge weight).

```
gremlin>  g.V().hasLabel('A').
......1>     repeat(outE().inV().simplePath()).until(hasLabel('Z')).path().by(label)
==>[A,knows,F,knows,Z]
==>[A,knows,F,knows,H,knows,Z]
==>[A,knows,C,knows,F,knows,Z]
==>[A,knows,B,knows,C,knows,F,knows,Z]
==>[A,knows,C,knows,D,knows,F,knows,Z]
==>[A,knows,C,knows,F,knows,H,knows,Z]
==>[A,knows,B,knows,C,knows,D,knows,F,knows,Z]
==>[A,knows,B,knows,C,knows,F,knows,H,knows,Z]
==>[A,knows,C,knows,D,knows,F,knows,H,knows,Z]
==>[A,knows,B,knows,C,knows,D,knows,F,knows,H,knows,Z]
```

Note that one of the edges does not have a weight. We can find the paths with the lightest weights (where no weight is treated as a zero value) as follows:

```
gremlin> g.withSack(0).V().
......1>       hasLabel('A').
......2>       repeat(outE().sack(sum).by(coalesce(values('weight'),constant(0))).inV()).
......3>       until(hasLabel('Z')).
......4>       order().by(sack(),asc).
......5>       path().
......6>         by(label)
==>[A,knows,B,knows,C,knows,F,knows,Z]
==>[A,knows,C,knows,F,knows,Z]
==>[A,knows,B,knows,C,knows,D,knows,F,knows,Z]
==>[A,knows,B,knows,C,knows,F,knows,H,knows,Z]
==>[A,knows,C,knows,D,knows,F,knows,Z]
==>[A,knows,C,knows,F,knows,H,knows,Z]
==>[A,knows,B,knows,C,knows,D,knows,F,knows,H,knows,Z]
==>[A,knows,C,knows,D,knows,F,knows,H,knows,Z]
==>[A,knows,F,knows,Z]
==>[A,knows,F,knows,H,knows,Z]
```

Just to prove that things are working as expected we can add the total weight value to each result.

```
gremlin> g.withSack(0).V().
......1>       hasLabel('A').
......2>       repeat(outE().sack(sum).by(coalesce(values('weight'),constant(0))).inV()).
......3>       until(hasLabel('Z')).
......4>       order().by(sack(),asc).
......5>       local(
......6>         union(
......7>           path().
......8>             by(label),
......9>           sack()).
.....10>         fold())
==>[[A,knows,B,knows,C,knows,F,knows,Z],0.4]
==>[[A,knows,C,knows,F,knows,Z],0.6]
==>[[A,knows,B,knows,C,knows,D,knows,F,knows,Z],0.8]
==>[[A,knows,B,knows,C,knows,F,knows,H,knows,Z],0.8]
==>[[A,knows,C,knows,D,knows,F,knows,Z],1.0]
==>[[A,knows,C,knows,F,knows,H,knows,Z],1.0]
==>[[A,knows,B,knows,C,knows,D,knows,F,knows,H,knows,Z],1.2]
==>[[A,knows,C,knows,D,knows,F,knows,H,knows,Z],1.4]
==>[[A,knows,F,knows,Z],3.6]
==>[[A,knows,F,knows,H,knows,Z],4.0]
```